# "You need to specify at least one testng.xml, one class or one method"

Tags: selenium

My code is just to open browser (I have done it done by creating new project)

```
package com.SheetUpdate.code;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SheetCode1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Rajesh\\Downloads\\selenium jars\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://msguides.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you try to run it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are running the project as TestNG Test. If you just want to execute the simple Java project then `Right click on class name` > `Run As..` > `Java Application`

But if you want to run the class as TestNG then you have to pull the `@Test` annotation on your method instead of main method e.g.

```
@Test
public void browserSetup { 

 // write browser setup code here

}
```

You can execute the single class directly by right click on the `class name > Run As > TestNG test`

OR

You can create the `testng.xml` file and mention the said class details there and execute that xml file